# How to catch cucumberJS timeouts and not fail steps

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cucumberjs

So I have a cucumberJS/PuppeteerJS solution for test automation.  I have an issue when it comes to checking for a button.  There is a Load More button that will appear when there are more items to load on a list and not appear when all the items have appeared.

Example: The list of 10 things will only show 4 at first and the Load More button.  You select the Load More button and now 8 will show.  You selected it again and all 10 items are there, and the Load More button is no longer present.

I have some feature files which call a step_definition which in turn calls some functions in world.js

I have some code to check if the button is there:

```
const isElementVisible = async (cssSelector) => {
    return Promise.resolve(
        page.waitForSelector(cssSelector, { visible: true, timeout: settings._5000 })
    ).then(() => {
        return true;
    }).catch(() => {
        return false;
    });
};
```

This is called by:

```
// Select Load More Agencies button if button is there
async clickButtonLoadMore() {
    // check to see if element is visible
    let selectorForLoadMoreButton = '[data-test-button="Load More"]';
    let loadMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(selectorForLoadMoreButton);
    // If button visible, select it
    while (loadMoreVisible) {
        await page
            .click('[data-test-button="Load More"]');
        loadMoreVisible = await isElementVisible(selectorForLoadMoreButton);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I've select the Load More button on the third time, like in the example above, the time-out (in the page.waitForSelector) fails to the feature file level and doesn't get handled by the promise.

```
   ✔ When the View List button is selected on the navigation pane # features/step_definitions/console_steps.js:7
   ✖ And click the Load More # features/step_definitions/console_steps.js:31
   Error: No node found for selector: [data-test-button="Load More"]
           at assert (/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint04/epay-test-automation/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:229:11)
           at DOMWorld.click 
(/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint04/epay-test-automation/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:359:5)
           at <anonymous>
         -- ASYNC --
           at Frame.<anonymous> (/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint04/epay-test-automation/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:108:27)
           at Page.click (/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint04/epay-test-automation/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1021:29)
           at ePayApp.clickButtonLoadMore (/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint04/epay-test-automation/features/support/world.js:777:6)
           at <anonymous>
   - And click the Manage Agency Data row that has the Mega Agency label # features/step_definitions/console_steps.js:11
   - And click Agency Accounts # features/step_definitions/console_steps.js:15
```

The selector is found the first two times, but the third, the button is not there and the selector times-out.  Instead of being caught, it goes to cucumber.

How can I correct this so that the time-out is caught and handled by the promise?

Comment: It looks like the `isElementVisible` method is the one timing out. You need to set a total the timeout on that method

Comment: I added more details.  If the time out happened during the waitForSelector in the clickButtonLoadMore() function, then why wasn't it caught .catch() in the Promise?

Comment: Have you checked if the selenium code is faster than the application code? It could be possible that the isElementVisible is finding the element and returning true before the app is actually removing the button and then when you go to click the button has finally been removed. Could you put a wait in before each isElementVisible just a test to see if that is the problem

Comment: Hmmm...I'll put a time delay in and see if that helps.

Comment: Rats!  A time delay didn't work.